# É possível somar os valores das td usando querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber se é possível somar os valores contidos dentro da td utilizando querySelectorAll? E mostrar o resultado da soma no `span id="valor_total"` conforme exemplo do código abaixo.

```js
function somaTds() {
  var selecionados = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#tblEditavel vlr'));

  var total = selecionados.reduce(function(soma, el) {
    console.log(el.innerHTML);
    return soma + Number(el.value);
  }, 0);

  document.getElementById('valor_total').innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    currency: 'BRL'
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-condensed">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Valor</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Casa</td>
    <td class="vlr">R$ 200,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>89</td>
    <td>Loja</td>
    <td class="vlr">R$ 551,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td><span id="valor_total">somando...</span></td>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnSoma" onclick="somaTds()">Somar</button>
```

ao clicar no botão somar ele retorna um valor zerado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim perfeitamente possivel. Repara que tinhas um erro no seletor, faltando um `.` em `'#tblEditavel vlr'`, e `#tblEditavel` no HTML. E se não estás a usar `input` tens de usar `innerHTML.

Podias fazer isso assim:

```js
function somaTds() {
  var selecionados = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#tblEditavel .vlr'));

  var total = selecionados.reduce(function(soma, el) {
    var numero = el.innerHTML.slice(3).replace(',', '.');
    return soma + Number(numero);
  }, 0);

  document.getElementById('valor_total').innerHTML = 'R$ ' + total.toLocaleString('pt-br', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    currency: 'BRL'
  });
}
somaTds();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table id="tblEditavel" class="table table-condensed">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Valor</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Casa</td>
    <td class="vlr">R$ 200,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>89</td>
    <td>Loja</td>
    <td class="vlr">R$ 551,00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Total</td>
    <td><span id="valor_total">somando...</span></td>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnSoma" onclick="somaTds()">Somar</button>
```

Comment: +1 muito bom, cara.

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente o que eu estava precisando.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa converter o valor `"R$ 200,00"` para poder ser convertido por `Number`.

Utilize o `replace` para remover o  `R$` e transformar `,` em `.`.

Veja:

```js
var texto = 'R$ 200,00';

var numero = texto.replace(',', '.').replace('R$ ', '');


console.log(Number(numero));

console.log(Number(texto)); // aqui vai dar errado, vai dar NaN
```

Comment: sim as duas formas dão certo mas acabei optando por slice().